# Problema al llamar un 3er archivo html con ajax y Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

estoy intentando llamar un segundo archivo, desde otro archivo cargado con ajax + Jquery

El archivo principal, contiene un boton, que esta a la escucha de un evento, que cargara el contenedor de una archivo HTML. EL codigo del archivo principal es el siguiente:

```
<div class="container">
    <button class="waves-effect waves-light btn" id="boton1">Llamar archivo</button>
</div>

<div id="cargar_contenido">


</div>
<div id="cargar_contenido2">

</div>
```

Y el codigo javaScript el siguiente:

```
$(document).ready( function(){

    $("#boton1").click( function(){

        $("#cargar_contenido").load("match.html #container");
        console.log("El evento se ha desencadenado");    
    });


    $("#boton2").click( function(){

       $("#cargar").load("archivo.html #contenedor");
        console.log("EL segundo eveno se ha ejecutado");
    });


});
```

Cuando se cargue el primer contenedor del primer archivo llamado, solo se obtendra un botón cuyo ID="boton2" el problema viene cuando tengo que poner ese boton("boton2") a la escucha de un evento, se supone que al hacer click en ese segundo botón deba cargar un 3er archivo html, pero no se ejecuta el evento, y el 3er archivo no se carga.

Alguien tiene alguna idea de porque no se carga el archivo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te recomiendo cambiar tus 2 listeners de eventos click.

Lo que habías hecho no estaba mal solo que solo funcionan si el elemento que estas buscando en este caso `#boton2` esta ya creado en la pagina cuando se carga el **JavaScript**.

**Antes**

```
$(document).ready( function(){

    $("#boton1").click( function(){

        $("#cargar_contenido").load("match.html #container");
        console.log("El evento se ha desencadenado");    
    });


    $("#boton2").click( function(){

       $("#cargar").load("archivo.html #contenedor");
        console.log("EL segundo eveno se ha ejecutado");
    });


});
```

**Despues**

```
$(document).ready( function(){

    $(document).on("click", "#boton1", function(){

        $("#cargar_contenido").load("match.html #container");
        console.log("El evento se ha desencadenado");    
    });


    $(document).on("click", "#boton2", function(){

       $("#cargar").load("archivo.html #contenedor");
        console.log("EL segundo eveno se ha ejecutado");
    });


});
```

Este código te permitirá escuchar el **click** incluso cuando el elemento se haya creado después en el DOM.

Saludos!!